Can someone explain what is wrong with the train function of this simple linear regression model?
def predict(self, input):
    return (self.slope*input) + self.bias

def train(self,inputs,targets):
    N = len(inputs)
    predictions = np.array([self.predict(input) for input in inputs])
    errors  = np.array(targets)-predictions

    self.slope += ((np.dot(errors,np.array(inputs)))/N)*self.lr
    self.bias += (np.sum(errors) * self.lr)/N

The slope increases or decreases by a very high magnitude

how much is self.lr?

The primary issue is likely the learning rate (self.lr). If it's too high, parameter updates (for both the slope and bias) become too large, causing instability, such as oscillation or divergence. Start with a smaller learning rate and adjust based on how the model behaves.
Another key consideration is input scaling. If inputs vary widely, gradients can become large, resulting in excessive updates. Standardising the inputs (scaling to mean 0 and variance 1) can help:
inputs = (inputs - np.mean(inputs)) / np.std(inputs)

It is important to handle edge cases, such as division by zero, when standardising:
std = np.std(inputs)
if std != 0:
    inputs = (inputs - np.mean(inputs)) / std

Gradient clipping is something else to consider, but is generally unnecessary in linear regression. Instead, focus on proper learning rate and input scaling to ensure stability.
Here is an adapted version of your code:
def train(self, inputs, targets):
    N = len(inputs)

    # Standardize inputs (mean 0, variance 1)
    std = np.std(inputs)
    if std != 0:
        inputs = (inputs - np.mean(inputs)) / std

    # Vectorized prediction calculation
    predictions = self.slope * np.array(inputs) + self.bias
    errors = np.array(targets) - predictions

    # Gradient calculation
    gradient_slope = np.dot(errors, np.array(inputs)) / N
    gradient_bias = np.sum(errors) / N

    # Update slope and bias
    self.slope += gradient_slope * self.lr
    self.bias += gradient_bias * self.lr

Summing up:

Start with a lower learning rate to avoid unstable parameter updates.
Standardise inputs to prevent large gradients from unscaled values.
Gradient clipping is something to think about, but probably isn't necessary here, so the focus should be on proper learning rate and input scaling for stability.

